# Porque a classe "container" no Bootstrap deixa espaços laterais na página? Isso é normal?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, front-end

Porque a classe *"container"* no Bootstrap deixa espaços laterais na página? Isso é normal ou estou esquecendo algo?

Preciso saber também como alterar a altura de cada *row*, pois tentei usar o *height* e ele não reconhece.

[image: Print]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, é normal. Inclusive, isto [consta na documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#overview-container).

Se quiser aproveitar melhor o espaço lateral, pode usar a classe **`container-fluid`**.

Veja um exemplo. Obs.: Infelizmente não funciona direito no tamanho original, clique em "**Página Toda**" para testar.

```css
.blue { 
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="blue container">
Texto
</div>

<div class="blue container-fluid">
Texto
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado. Alterei o post adicionando uma segunda pergunta (antes de ver sua resposta), se puder responde-la tambem, ficaria grato

Comment: @Amauri Por favor, mantenha o foco único no post. Se a resposta solucionou seu problema, você pode marcá-la como correta usando o **✓** do lado esquerdo da mesma. Sobre a nova dúvida, você pode abrir uma nova pergunta, não tem porque evitar isto.